# How to do filter a list in Java8?

Tags: java

I'm used to C# and the lambda expressions, but i couldn't filter a java list based on certain criterias.

Ex:

```
List<MyObject> list;
```

I need to get all the MyObject that have a isMyFlag() true.

In C# is really easy using IEnumerable... Is there any similar to IEnumerable in Java?

Comment: well, Java8 comes with Lambda expressions available. Have you checked those?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

See the new [Stream API](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/package-summary.html) in Java 8

You need to do a filter and then collect the results in a list using the Stream API:

```
list.stream().filter(x -> x.isMyFlag()).collect(Collectors.toList());
```

Comment: You can also use methode reference instead of lambda expression: `.filter( x::isMyFlag )`

Answer (score 4):

With lambdas you could do the following:

```
List<MyObject> filteredList = list.stream().filter(myObj -> myObj.isMyFlag())
                                           .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

Answer (score 0):

To use the Stream API you need to call the stream() method.  This is perhaps a surprise coming from C# as you don't need to do this, but once you have got over that hurdle it should be much the same.

```
List<MyObject> list2 = list.stream()
                           .filter(m -> m.isMyFlag())
                           .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

Comment: `list` is not a method of `Stream<T>`. `collect` is the one you're thinking of.